# Language support for Form Recognizer

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Currently it supports English, Is there any timeline when other languages will be supported for Form Recognizer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not Microsoft's support team. Only they can answer and as such this question should be addressed to their customer service.

Answer (score 1):

We plan to support additional languages for Form Recognizer but there is currently no available public information on the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer will be GA this month. Tier 2 languages will be supported in coming releases.
Here is the doc to refer for further updates on the language support.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/language-support